# Finding the degree of $\alpha + \beta$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\alpha, \beta$ be algebraic over $F$ with degrees $m$ and $n$ respectively. If $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, how to find the degree of $\alpha + \beta$?

Comment: I think it's $m\times n$, but I can't prove it. I have to show that minimal polynomial of $\beta$ is irreducible in $F(\alpha)$

Comment: Yes, it's $mn$.The proof is not so easy.

Comment: @quasi ani links to the theory required to prove it? Actually I think $F(\alpha + \beta) = F(\alpha, \beta)$ would work too.

Comment: I have a written proof somewhere, not by me, but I doubt if I can find it. I'm not sure if it was for an arbitrary field $F$, or if it assumed $F=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @quasi If you find it, I would be eternally grateful :-)

Comment: @I'll look, but most likely, someone here can answer it.

Comment: One way of getting at this is using the resultant.  It will give you a polynomial, one of whose factors is $\alpha+\beta$.

Comment: Another way of getting this is to look at the automorphisms of $F(\alpha)$ over $F$ and $F(\beta)$ over $F$ and show that $\sigma(\alpha)+\tau(\beta)$ must also be a root of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha+\beta$.

Comment: @Santosh Linkha: I'm not sure, but I think you may need to assume that $F$ is separable.

Comment: @quasi assume $F$ is separable. My original question was to find the degree of extension $F(\alpha, \beta)$ over $F$. I thought it was easy if I transform it to $\alpha + \beta$.

Comment: Since $\gcd(m,n)=1$, it's automatic that $[F(\alpha,\beta):F]=mn$. So that's a much easier question than whether of not $F(\alpha+\beta):F]=mn$.

Comment: @quasi how is it's automatic that if gcd(m,n) = 1 then $[F(\alpha, \beta):F] =mn$? Any trick for it? I thought I might try something like this http://imgur.com/HMVnfAi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to the question of whether

$$[F(\alpha,\beta):F]=mn$$

the answer is an easy "yes".

From the chains

$$F \subset F(\alpha) \subset F(\alpha,\beta)$$

$$F \subset F(\beta) \subset F(\alpha,\beta)$$

it follows that
\begin{align*}
{\small\bullet}\;\;&[F(\alpha,\beta):F] \le mn\\[4pt]
{\small\bullet}\;\;&m\;\text{divides}\;[F(\alpha,\beta):F]\\[4pt]
{\small\bullet}\;\;&n\;\text{divides}\;[F(\alpha,\beta):F]\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

hence, since $\gcd(m,n)=1$, we must have

$$[F(\alpha,\beta):F]=mn$$

as claimed.